# Finding a function that fits several arguments

Tags: python, numpy, math, sympy, symbolic-math

I want to find a sympy function, that fulfills several arguments. It should go through several points and have a certain derivative at some points. How do I do that?

```py
values = np.array([1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0])
derivats = np.array([1.0, 3.0], [2.0, 5.0])
```

Please help me and my mathematical English is not that good, so please use words that I can google.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are looking for.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by that?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of functions you are looking for? Do they involve trigonometry, are they polynomials, exponentials, .... ?

Comment: Perhaps [`sympy.polys.polyfuncs.interpolate()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#extra-polynomial-manipulation-functions) will satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a interpretation with SymPy's `solve` ([docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html)) and polynomials, to give an idea of the possibilities:

```py
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x', real=True)
n = 4  # degree of the polynomial
a = [symbols('a%d' % i, real=True) for i in range(n)]
print(a)
f = sum([a[i]*x**i for i in range(n)])  # f is a polynomial of degree n
g = f.diff(x)
sol = solve([Eq(f.subs(x, 1), 2), Eq(f.subs(x, 2), 3), Eq(g.subs(x, 1), 3), Eq(g.subs(x, 2), 5), ], a)
print(sol)
print(f.subs(sol))
```

This prints:

```
{a0: -15, a1: 37, a2: -26, a3: 6}
6*x**3 - 26*x**2 + 37*x - 15
```

Directly working with your arrays, this could be:

```py
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x', real=True)
n = 4  # degree of the polynomial
a = [symbols('a%d' % i, real=True) for i in range(n)]
f = sum([a[i]*x**i for i in range(n)])  # f is a polynomial of degree n
g = f.diff(x)
values = [[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0]] # suppose an array of pairs [x, f(x)]
derivats = [[1.0, 3.0], [2.0, 5.0]]  # suppose an array of pairs [x, f'(x)]
equations = [Eq(f.subs(x, xi), yi) for xi, yi in values] + [Eq(g.subs(x, xi), yi) for xi, yi in derivats]
sol = solve(equations)
print(sol)
print(f.subs(sol))
```

This outputs:

```
{a0: -15.0000000000000, a1: 37.0000000000000, a2: -26.0000000000000, a3: 6.00000000000000}
6.0*x**3 - 26.0*x**2 + 37.0*x - 15.0
```

Note that SymPy is less happy to work with reals than with integers and fractions.